# How to check if value is enum?

Tags: dart

I would like to check if a value in dart is an Enum, and if so, serialize it automatically.

My sticking point is how to test if a value is an enum.

This is how I am testing for other types

```
if (T == int)
  val = prefs.getInt(this._key);
else if (T == double)
  val = prefs.getDouble(this._key);
else if (T == bool)
  val = prefs.getBool(this._key);
else if (T == String)
  val = prefs.getString(this._key);
else if ([""] is T)
  val = prefs.getStringList(this._key);
```

but I cannot seem to compare `T` to an `enum`

Since all enums have the same methods I was hoping to sense them and handle them accordingly

Comment: You can only check if a value is of a specific enum, not any enum.

Answer (score 23):

## **As of late 2021, all enums extend `Enum`**

You can now finally use `is Enum` directly:

```
enum MyEnum {one, two, three}

var x = "a";
var y = MyEnum.one;

print(x is Enum); // false
print(y is Enum); // true
```

Which also means you can now create extensions for enums:

```
extension EnumExtension on Enum { ... }
```

Comment: Supported by `dart` `@Since("2.14")`

Answer (score 12):

If you need to check is `dynamic` value enum type. You can use the next approach. The main idea is quite similar to @Oniya Daniel's answer.

```
 enum Fruit {
   banana,
   apple,
   orange,
 }
```

Next method to check `isEnum` condition

```
 bool isEnum(dynamic data) {
   final split = data.toString().split('.');
   return split.length > 1 && split[0] == data.runtimeType.toString();
 }
```

Test result below

```
  test('check enum runtime', () {
    expect(isEnum(Fruit.banana), true);
    expect(isEnum(null), false);
    expect(isEnum(''), false);
    expect(isEnum('banana'), false);
  });
```

P.S.: to get enum String value good to use `describeEnum(<enum_value>)` from the `package:flutter/foundation.dart`

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `enum` to a `list` and check if the list contains the value you intend to check.

```
enum ObjectType {
    TypeA, TypeB
}

// checking against enum values
print(ObjectType.values.contains(ObjectType.TypeA));        // true
print(ObjectType.values.contains(ObjectType.TypeB));        // true

// checking against string value
print(ObjectType.values.contains("ObjectType.TypeA"));    // false

// checking against boolean
print(ObjectType.values.contains(false));   // false

// checking against int
print(ObjectType.values.contains(234));       // false

// checking against double
print(ObjectType.values.contains(2.345));    // false
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, or I would have added a statement to the answer by @Dmitry Puzak. In Dmitry's method, if `data` is passed as the String `"String.3.0.1"`, for instance, the method will incorrectly identify the parameter as an enum. The flutter-provided method, `describeEnum`, attempts to check that it's parameter is an enum and throws an exception if it's not, but in my experience the exception isn't always thrown when the parameter to `describeEnum` is a String value containing dots.

For a project I'm working, I modified Dmitry's `isEnum` method to the following, adding the first `if` block inside the method:

```
bool isEnum(dynamic data) {
  if (data.runtimeType == "".runtimeType) {
    return false;
  }
  final split = data.toString().split('.');
  return split.length > 1 && split[0] == data.runtimeType.toString();
}
```

This makes sure to return `false` for any String parameter.

I can't offhand think of any other instance where the runtime type of a variable could possibly match the first part of the `split` done on the `toString()` return value.